# Vq not working and it works in another file with the same idea

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to implement an artificial neural network that I just trained using this code.

```
import numpy as np
import os

training_path = 'Imagenes/train'
training_names = os.listdir(training_path)

image_paths = []
image_classes = []
class_id = 0

def imglist(path):
    return [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]

for training_name in training_names:
    dir = os.path.join(training_path, training_name)
    class_path = imglist(dir)
    image_paths += class_path
    image_classes += [class_id]*len(class_path)
    class_id+=1

des_list = []

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(100)

for image_path in image_paths:
    im = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)
    kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(im, None)
    des_list.append((image_path, des))

descriptors = des_list[0][1]
for image_path, descriptor in des_list[1:]:
    descriptors = np.vstack((descriptors,descriptor))

descriptors_float = descriptors.astype(float)

from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq

k = 1000

voc, variance = kmeans(descriptors_float, k, 1)


im_features = np.zeros((len(image_paths), k), "float32")
for i in range(len(image_paths)):
    words, distance = vq(des_list[i][1], voc)
    for w in words:
        im_features[i][w] += 1

nbr_ocurrences = np.sum((im_features > 0) * 1, axis = 0)
idf = np.array(np.log((1.0*len(image_paths)+1) / (1.0*nbr_ocurrences + 1)), 'float32')

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
stdSlr = StandardScaler().fit(im_features)
im_features = stdSlr.transform(im_features)

print(np.shape(im_features))
print(np.shape(image_classes))
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,50), max_iter=5000, alpha=0.001,
                     solver='sgd', verbose=10,  random_state=21,tol=0.000000001)
clf.fit(im_features, np.array(image_classes))

from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump((clf, training_names, stdSlr, k, voc), 'sift.pkl', compress = 3)
```

Well basically that's it and what I'm trying to implement is this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib
#Cargando parámetros del modelo, clases y desviaciones estandar par normalizar, además de los clusters
clf, class_names, stdSlr, k, voc = joblib.load('sift.pkl')
#Creando SIFT
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(100)
#Objeto de video
video = cv2.VideoCapture('video2.mp4')
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

#Ciclo infinito
while True:
    #Leer siguiente cuadro
    ret, frame = video.read()
    #Si hay siguiente cuadro, ret es TRUE de lo contrario es false y se rompe el ciclo
    if ret:
        porcentaje_escala = 100 # percent of original size
        width = int(frame.shape[1] * porcentaje_escala / 100)
        height = int(frame.shape[0] * porcentaje_escala / 100)
        dim = (width, height) 
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA) 
        #Mostramos el cuadro leído
        cv2.imshow('Video Original', frame)
        #Convertimos el cuadro a escala de grises para procesarlo
        frame_gris = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('Escala de Grises',frame_gris)       
        #Aplicamos MOG acá
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame_gris)     
        #Le hacemos thresholding para eliminar las sombras que el MOG2 deja en gris
        ret,fgmask = cv2.threshold(fgmask,250,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        #Aplicamos un pequeño filtro para quitarle ruido a la máscara
        fgmask = cv2.GaussianBlur(fgmask,(3,3),0)
        #Ahora vamos a dilatar y erosionar un poco la máscara para poder darle un espacio blanco al objeto
        #no que detecte la forma sino sólo su espacio
        kernel = np.ones((8,8),np.uint8)
        fgmask = cv2.dilate(fgmask,kernel,iterations = 1)
        fgmask = cv2.erode(fgmask,kernel,iterations = 1)
        cv2.imshow('Mascara de MOG2',fgmask)                
        #Ahora hacemos el AND bit a bit de la máscara y la imagen original
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask = fgmask)
        cv2.imshow('resultado',res)
        #Hallamos los componentes que comparten bits blancos en la imagen
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
        #Se dibuja cada contorno si su alto y ancho es mayor a 20 pixeles                       
        ROI=[]
        for c in contours:
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)           
            if((w>20) and (h>20)):                  
                ROI.append(frame[x:x+w,y:y+h])
        ROI_Valida=[]
        for i in range(len(ROI)):
            if(np.shape(ROI[i])[0] > 0):
                ROI_Valida.append(ROI[i])

        for i in range(len(ROI_Valida)):
            kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(ROI_Valida[i], None)            
            test_features = np.zeros(k, "float32")
            from scipy.cluster.vq import vq         
            words, distance = vq(des, voc)
            for w in words:
                test_features[w] += 1
        Mostramos la imagen final               
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break;
    else:
        break;
```

However in this line in the implementation

`words, distance = vq(des, voc)`

I'm getting the next error

Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Universidad\Trabajo de Grado\Pruebas\p2.py", line 60, in     words, distance = vq(des, voc)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\vq.py", line 201, in vq obs = _asarray_validated(obs, check_finite=check_finite)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy_lib_util.py", line 249, in _asarray_validated raise ValueError('object arrays are not supported')
ValueError: object arrays are not supported

Which doesn't make sense to me as it's the same line used in training with a set of matrix.

I'd appreciate any help.